# Can rsync's file hash check be disable?

Tags: rsync, coreutils

I am updating an OS X system from Ubunutu and I would prefer if the file difference was only checked by time and filesize as the OS X has a very slow disk and I believe this may speed up the process.

I believe it's also used to verify the transfer was successful. I am ok foregoing this check.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `rsync` checks for changed files comparing metadata (size, permission, mtime, etc) only.

To enable data checksumming when checking for file changes, you had to explicitly pass the `--checksum` option.

Answer (score 0):

From the rsync man page:

```
   -c, --checksum
          This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and  are  in  need  of  a
          transfer.   Without  this  option,  rsync uses a “quick check” that (by default) checks if
          each file’s size and time of last modification match  between  the  sender  and  receiver.
          This  option  changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that has a matching
          size.  Generating the checksums means that both sides will expend a lot of disk I/O  read-
          ing  all the data in the files in the transfer (and this is prior to any reading that will
          be done to transfer changed files), so this can slow things down significantly.

          The sending side generates its checksums while it  is  doing  the  file-system  scan  that
          builds  the  list of the available files.  The receiver generates its checksums when it is
          scanning for changed files, and will checksum any file that has the same size as the  cor-
          responding  sender’s  file:   files  with  either a changed size or a changed checksum are
          selected for transfer.

          Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed  on
          the  receiving  side  by  checking  a whole-file checksum that is generated as the file is
          transferred, but that automatic after-the-transfer verification has  nothing  to  do  with
          this option’s before-the-transfer “Does this file need to be updated?” check.

          For  protocol  30  and  beyond  (first supported in 3.0.0), the checksum used is MD5.  For
          older protocols, the checksum used is MD4.
```

So, it looks like as long as you don't specify -c then it won't do file checksums before transferring. But it will still do them after transfer. I see nothing in the man page indicating that those after checks can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rsync` with option `--no-checksum`